# Difficult Functions Evaluation Problem

Tags: functions

I have a question about finding the value of a certain function that I cannot wrap my head around.

The question is:  Given a function $f(x)$ satisfying $$f(x) + 2f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right) = x,$$ Then find $f(2).$

So far, I have tried plugging 2 into the original equation to yield $f(2) + 2f(-1) = 2.$

Next, I plugged $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}$ into the original equation to yield $\displaystyle f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) + 2f(2) = \frac{1}{2}$.

However, I do not know how to solve this system of equations for $f(2).$

Please let me know of any hints you may have. Many thanks.

Comment: Some hints for formatting in MathJax are [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).  It would be much easier to read the question if you do that.  Your approach of finding good values to plug in for $x$ is a good one.  I wrote an answer, but T. Boners supplied more info.

Comment: Thank you, Ross. I am new to the website and did not know how MathJax worked, so I appreciate your direction to the tips page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two equations, but three variables: Namely, $f(2), f(-1)$ and $f(1/2)$. Try setting $x = -1$ to also get the equation

$$f(-1) + 2 f\left( \frac 1 2\right) = \frac 1 2$$

This is a third equation, from which you can solve the system of three.

Answer (score 2):

Given $$f(x)+2f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right) = x...................(1)$$

Replace $\displaystyle x\rightarrow \frac{1}{1-x}\;,$ We get

$$f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)+2f\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right) = \frac{1}{1-x}.......(2)$$

Again replace $\displaystyle x\rightarrow \frac{1}{1-x}\;,$ We get

$$f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)+2f(x) = \frac{x-1}{x}..............(3)$$

Now from $(1)$ and $(2)$

$$f(x)-4f\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)=x-\frac{2}{1-x}..........(4)$$

Multiply $(3)$ by $4\;,$ We get

$$4f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)+8f(x) = \frac{4(x-1)}{x}..........(5)$$

Add $(4)$ and $(5)$

$$9f(x) = x-\frac{2}{1-x}+\frac{4(x-1)}{x}$$

So $$9f(2)=2+2+2=6\Rightarrow f(2) = \frac{2}{3}$$