# Evaluate this function.

Tags: functions

$f(x) + f(\frac{1}{x-1}) = \frac{x}{x-1}$

Can you help me evaluate this function?
I have tried to substitute values into $x$ to find the function, use Maclaurin series expansion and...
And how do I solve these type of questions?

Comment: Sorry i am new to stackexchange

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1860910/difficult-functions-evaluation-problem

Comment: Do you want to evaluate it at a specific value of x or find an analytic form for $f(x)$ ?

Comment: @juantheron That solution is fine but is there anyway for solving f(g(x))+f(h(x))=j(x) for arbitary functions g(x),h(x) and j(x)

Comment: @ivan I want to find a closed form of f(x)

Comment: Do you have any more information about $f$? for example, what it's domain is?

Comment: @Morgan Rogers No. But i believe that f(x) is continous for all x except for x=1 and that that f(x) might be the sum of the inverses of x^n.

Comment: We might need some more information about $f(x)$. Replacing $x \to 1/x$ we can generate

$$ f\left( {\frac{1}{x}} \right) + f\left( {\frac{x}{{1 - x}}} \right) = \frac{1}{{1 - x}} $$

which has a very similar form unto sign difference. So if its an odd function it might have a different form than if its even.

Comment: @Ivan Abraham can you elaborate more?